# Is it faster to union sets or check the whole list for a duplicate?

Tags: python, set

Sorry for the poorly worded title but I asked a question earlier about getting a unique list of items from two lists. People told me to make the list -> sets and then union.

So now I'm wondering if it's faster to:

1. While adding **one** item to a list, scan the whole list for duplicates.
2. Make that one item a set and then union sets.

I should probably just read up on sets in hindsight...

In Python, by the way - sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: In what language? With what library? There's no answer to this in the abstract.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `timeit` module?  You can gather some data and include the `timeit` results as part of your question.

Comment: A set is a container, the same as a list is. You don't make one item into a set, you make the entire list into a set. You don't put the elements into the set one at a time. You just create the set from the list.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: but why start with a list instead of a set ? It would be even better if no datatype change was needed. I mean **never** converting is faster than converting **once**.

Comment: @kriss Sure; but it's possible he needed it as a list somewhere else...

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: OK, but I am very curious to know the use case of a list where items order is not important *and* which must not have duplicates. The typical next step would be to sort it before sending it to some output function and a set is as good as a list for that...

Comment: @kriss ... it's possible that some other part of the code needed a list (e.g. for random access or slicing), and now that it's finished, a set must be constructed from the resulting list.

Comment: @Karl Knetchel: well, it's *possible*, still curious of the actual problem. As I understand the question about adding items one by one, I wonder it the reason behind asking the question that way is not some call to a process that produce these items one by one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

as you can see extending one list by another end then remove duplicates by making set
is the fastest way(at least in python;))

```
>>> def foo():
...     """
...     extending one list by another end then remove duplicates by making set
...     """
...     l1 = range(200)
...     l2 = range(150, 250)
...     l1.extend(l2)
...     set(l1)
... 
>>> def bar():
...     """
...     checking if element is on one list end adding it only if not
...     """
...     l1 = range(200)
...     l2 = range(150, 250)
...     for elem in l2:
...             if elem not in l1:
...                     l1.append(elem)
... 
>>> def baz():
...     """
...     making sets from both lists and then union from them
...     """
...     l1 = range(200)
...     l2 = range(150, 250)
...     set(l1) | set(l2)
... 
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer(foo).timeit(10000)
0.265153169631958
>>> Timer(bar).timeit(10000)
7.921358108520508
>>> Timer(baz).timeit(10000)
0.3845551013946533
>>>
```

Comment: `set(itertools.chain(l1,l2))` is only a tiny bit slower and doesn't need to modify `l1`. Also more memory efficient if l1 and l2 are large

Comment: doing `x = set(l1); x.update(l2)` is as fast as the `foo` method (maybe slightly faster on my computer) and uses less memory. It also does not modify `l1`.

Comment: or yet faster `set(l1).union(l2)` does not modify anything and also memory efficient.

Comment: @kriss, did you time it? That is about 25% slower than using the update method by my count. I'm pretty sure that using the union like that is slower because it first creates the `set(l1)` and then creates another set (which it returns) when it does the union.

Comment: @Justin Peel: Yes, I did time it, but I had a typo in my test set, yours I faster (but still slower in most cases - three times in this scenario - than extending initial list).

Comment: @kriss, 3 times slower than extending initial list? For what values of `l1` and `l2`? I'm just not seeing the same results. I'm actually getting that the set-update method is generally a little bit faster than extending. Maybe I'm not thinking broadly enough in my testing.

Comment: @Justin Peel: Sorry (again), I will put a dunce cap on my head an program with it all day next monday... and also I should get more sleep, my error again... Really I accidentaly removed the conversion to set from the list extension sample, no wonder it did marvels when timing it. This is an excellent reminder than when things looks too good I should double check before speaking of it...

Comment: @kriss, no problem. We all have that happen sometimes. I was just making sure that it wasn't my turn.

Answer (score 13):

I really like the approach virhilo did, but it's a pretty specific set of data he was testing. In all this don't just test the functions, but test them how you'll be doing it. I put together a much more exhaustive test set. It runs each function you specify (with just a little decorator) through a list of comparisons, and figures out how long each function takes and therefore how much slower it is. The result is that it's not always clear which function you should be doing without knowing more about the size, overlap and type of your data.

Here's my test program, below will be the output.

```
from timeit import Timer
from copy import copy
import random
import sys

funcs = []

class timeMe(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        funcs.append(f)
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

@timeMe
def extend_list_then_set(input1, input2):
    """
    extending one list by another end then remove duplicates by making set
    """
    l1 = copy(input1)
    l2 = copy(input2)
    l1.extend(l2)
    set(l1)

@timeMe
def per_element_append_to_list(input1, input2):
    """
    checking if element is on one list end adding it only if not
    """
    l1 = copy(input1)
    l2 = copy(input2)
    for elem in l2:
            if elem not in l1:
                    l1.append(elem)

@timeMe
def union_sets(input1, input2):
    """
    making sets from both lists and then union from them
    """
    l1 = copy(input1)
    l2 = copy(input2)
    set(l1) | set(l2)

@timeMe
def set_from_one_add_from_two(input1, input2):
    """
    make set from list 1, then add elements for set 2
    """
    l1 = copy(input1)
    l2 = copy(input2)
    l1 = set(l1)
    for element in l2:
        l1.add(element)

@timeMe
def set_from_one_union_two(input1, input2):
    """
    make set from list 1, then union list 2
    """
    l1 = copy(input1)
    l2 = copy(input2)
    x = set(l1).union(l2)

@timeMe
def chain_then_set(input1, input2):
    """
    chain l1 & l2, then make a set out of that
    """
    l1 = copy(input1)
    l2 = copy(input2)
    set(itertools.chain(l1, l2))

def run_results(l1, l2, times):
    for f in funcs:
        t = Timer('%s(l1, l2)' % f.__name__,
            'from __main__ import %s; l1 = %s; l2 = %s' % (f.__name__, l1, l2))
        yield (f.__name__, t.timeit(times))    

test_datasets = [
    ('original, small, some overlap', range(200), range(150, 250), 10000),
    ('no overlap: l1 = [1], l2 = [2..100]', [1], range(2, 100), 10000),
    ('lots of overlap: l1 = [1], l2 = [1]*100', [1], [1]*100, 10000),
    ('50 random ints below 2000 in each', [random.randint(0, 2000) for x in range(50)], [random.randint(0, 2000) for x in range(50)], 10000),
    ('50 elements in each, no overlap', range(50), range(51, 100), 10000),
    ('50 elements in each, total overlap', range(50), range(50), 10000),
    ('500 random ints below 500 in each', [random.randint(0, 500) for x in range(500)], [random.randint(0, 500) for x in range(500)], 1000),
    ('500 random ints below 2000 in each', [random.randint(0, 2000) for x in range(500)], [random.randint(0, 2000) for x in range(500)], 1000),
    ('500 random ints below 200000 in each', [random.randint(0, 200000) for x in range(500)], [random.randint(0, 200000) for x in range(500)], 1000),
    ('500 elements in each, no overlap', range(500), range(501, 1000), 10000),
    ('500 elements in each, total overlap', range(500), range(500), 10000),
    ('10000 random ints below 200000 in each', [random.randint(0, 200000) for x in range(10000)], [random.randint(0, 200000) for x in range(10000)], 50),
    ('10000 elements in each, no overlap', range(10000), range(10001, 20000), 10),
    ('10000 elements in each, total overlap', range(10000), range(10000), 10),
    ('original lists 100 times', range(200)*100, range(150, 250)*100, 10),
]

fullresults = []
for description, l1, l2, times in test_datasets:
    print "Now running %s times: %s" % (times, description)
    results = list(run_results(l1, l2, times))
    speedresults = [x for x in sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])]
    for name, speed in results:
        finish = speedresults.index((name, speed)) + 1
        timesslower = speed / speedresults[0][1]
        fullresults.append((description, name, speed, finish, timesslower))
        print '\t', finish, ('%.2fx' % timesslower).ljust(10), name.ljust(40), speed

print
import csv
out = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
out.writerow(('Test', 'Function', 'Speed', 'Place', 'timesslower'))
out.writerows(fullresults)
```

## The results

My point here is to encourage you to test with your data, so I don't want to harp on specifics. However... The first extend method is the fastest average method, but set_from_one_union_two (`x = set(l1).union(l2)`) wins a few of times. You can get more details if you run the script yourself.

The numbers I'm reporting are the number of times slower this function is than the fatest function on that test. If it was the fastest, it will be 1.

```
                                            Functions                                                                                                                           
Tests                                       extend_list_then_set     per_element_append_to_list    set_from_one_add_from_two  set_from_one_union_two     union_sets      chain_then_set
original, small, some overlap               1                          25.04                        1.53                        1.18                       1.39           1.08
no overlap: l1 = [1], l2 = [2..100]         1.08                       13.31                        2.10                        1                          1.27           1.07
lots of overlap: l1 = [1], l2 = [1]*100     1.10                        1.30                        2.43                        1                          1.25           1.05
50 random ints below 2000 in each           1                           7.76                        1.35                        1.20                       1.31           1   
50 elements in each, no overlap             1                           9.00                        1.48                        1.13                       1.18           1.10
50 elements in each, total overlap          1.08                        4.07                        1.64                        1.04                       1.41           1   
500 random ints below 500 in each           1.16                       68.24                        1.75                        1                          1.28           1.03
500 random ints below 2000 in each          1                         102.42                        1.64                        1.43                       1.81           1.20
500 random ints below 200000 in each        1.14                      118.96                        1.99                        1.52                       1.98           1   
500 elements in each, no overlap            1.01                      145.84                        1.86                        1.25                       1.53           1   
500 elements in each, total overlap         1                          53.10                        1.95                        1.16                       1.57           1.05          
10000 random ints below 200000 in each      1                        2588.99                        1.73                        1.35                       1.88           1.12
10000 elements in each, no overlap          1                        3164.01                        1.91                        1.26                       1.65           1.02
10000 elements in each, total overlap       1                        1068.67                        1.89                        1.26                       1.70           1.05
original lists 100 times                    1.11                     2068.06                        2.03                        1                          1.04           1.17

                                 Average    1.04                      629.25                       1.82                         1.19                       1.48           1.06
                      Standard Deviation    0.05                     1040.76                       0.26                         0.15                       0.26           0.05
                                     Max    1.16                     3164.01                       2.43                         1.52                       1.98           1.20
```

Comment: +1 for the nice test set. There is still still a few implementations to add to the test, like ichain from @gnibbler. Also it is dubious that in real use the list build time (l1.copy()) should be counted... in some cases like union of set copying l1 is just a loss of time, and in all cases copying l2 is totally useless (l2 was not modified at beginning), that may change "winner"... overall, knowing more about the actual use case of the OP would be interesting to interpret results.

Comment: I agree that the copy operation is odd, but all of them do it so it should be similarly impactful for all. I wanted to level the playing field of who modifies the original l1 and who doesn't as much as possible, with a consistent aspect. I'll add @gnibbler's chain now.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest thing you can do is build two sets from the lists and take the union of them. Both set construction from list and set union are implemented in the runtime, in very optimized C, so it is very fast.

In code, if the lists are `l1` and `l2`, you can do

```
unique_elems = set(l1) | set(l2)
```

EDIT: as @kriss notes, extending `l1` with `l2` is faster. This code however doesn't change `l1`, and works also if `l1` and `l2` are generic iterables.

Comment: as you can see looking at @virhilo answer, yours is not true. It is faster to extend the initial list then converting to set. It makes sense as is also is calling very optimized C, and extend checks nearly nothing and is much simpler than building a set. However, I do not downvote as I suspect that your proposal may still be faster with some testsets (like lists containing many duplicates at start).

Comment: I checked with `l1 = range(200) * 100; l2 = range(150, 250) * 100` using @virhilo code and indeed converting both lists to sets becomes slightly faster than first extending the initial list... but I believe this testset is an extreme case.

Comment: @kriss: it is faster if there are lots of duplicates. Anyway, I still prefer this code because it doesn't have side-effects on the first list (while @virhilo's code does) and it works also if `l1` and `l2` are iterables that are not `list`s

Comment: You can also do `newlist = list(l1); newlist.extend(l2); return newlist;` that also works on any iterable and does not modify the initial list, or (even faster) `return set(l1).union(l2)` this last one avoid one operation (constructing the second set) compared to your version.

Answer (score 1):

All depends of what you have as input and want as output.

If you have a list `li` at the beginning and want to get a modified list in the end, then the faster method is `if not elt in li: li.append(elt)` the problem is converting initial list to set, then converting back to list which is way too slow.

But if you can work with a set `s` at all time (you don't care about the order of the list, and methods receiving it just need some iterable), just doing `s.add(elt)` is faster.

If in the beginning you have to lists and want a list in the end, even with final conversion from list set to list, it is faster to manage unicity of items using sets, but you can easily check looking at the exemple provided by @virhilo in it's answer, than concatenating the two lists using extend, then converting the result to set is faster than converting the two lists to sets and performing an union.

I don't know exactly what are the constraints of your programs, but if unicity is as important as it seems, and if keeping insertion order is not necessary, you would be well advised to use sets at all time, never changing them to lists. Most algorithms will work for both anyway, thanks to *Duck Typing* as they both are different kinds of iterables.