# What are the differences between these two methods of getting the union of 2 lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, set

Given two lists in Python:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'b','e']
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5,'a','b','c','d',]
```

What are the differences between these two methods of getting the union of the two lists?

```
>>> set(a).union(set(b))
set(['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
>>> set(a+b)
set(['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
```

Are there logical differences (i.e. situations where these two methods may not provide identical results)? Are there performance implications?

Comment: whoever flagged this question as unclear, please retract the flag. It's pretty clear IMO

Answer (score 2):

The implementation detail is different:

**Method A:**

1. create a set from the elements of the list `a`
2. create a set from the elements of the list `b`
3. merges using `set.union` on the sets from 1 and 2

Note that step 2. is wasteful here.  `set(a).union(b)` would work just as well.

**Method B:**

1. creates a new list from the elements of list `a` and list `b`
2. creates a set from the list that was created in 1

**There is no difference in the result.**  Just different ways to do the same thing.  Method B is faster, because there are fewer intermediate collections used.

Comment: I would think that `set(a).union(b)` would be fastest for large inputs (though I have nothing to back that up, on my phone atm :) )

Comment: an answer to your comment @Mitch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674208/is-it-faster-to-union-sets-or-check-the-whole-list-for-a-duplicate

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the order items appear in a `set` (when iterating or printing) is undefined and implementation dependent. It's possible that two different ways of building equal sets will result in different iteration orders. That shouldn't matter to any sensible code (which will treat the iteration order as arbitrary), but it could be a *small* difference between the results of the two approaches in the question.